# How to stop cumulative values in graph after no values?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I used the New quick measure assistant to get a cumulative view of data, I was able to achieve somewhat the result I was looking for, however, the line chart/table shows the total in the following months where there is no data.

For example, 1246 in Nov 2019 should be 0 by Dec 2019 given that there's no more information for the latter.

How can I stop this from happening?

[image]

This is the code the quick measure helped me create:

```
Qty running total in Month = 
CALCULATE(
SUM('Table'[Qty]),
FILTER(
    CALCULATETABLE(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'Sort Order Table',
            'Sort Order Table'[Month Number],
            'Sort Order Table'[Month]
        ),
        ALLSELECTED('Sort Order Table')
    ),
    ISONORAFTER(
        'Sort Order Table'[Month Number], MAX('Sort Order Table'[Month Number]), DESC,
        'Sort Order Table'[Month], MAX('Sort Order Table'[Month]), DESC
    )
)
)
```

I tried getting a cumulative view, but it continues flat at doesn't stop after the final value is added.